# Cannot make connection to metamask

Tags: javascript, ethereum, blockchain, cdn, ethers.js

I want to make connection to metamask and get the account balance :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test ethereum metamask</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script type="module">
            import { ethers } from "https://cdn.ethers.io/lib/ethers-5.2.esm.min.js";
            const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
            const balance = await provider.getBalance("0xE0552897c6495D7efb98F3823cd48bf19e703D0b");
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        test
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log("========== balance =", balance);
    </script>
</html>
```

At runtime I get console errors : `Uncaught ReferenceError: balance is not defined` and `Access to script at 'https://cdn.ethers.io/lib/ethers-5.2.esm.min.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`

So what is the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use cloudflare cdn and put the `console.log("========== balance =", balance);` into the first script. module scripts are `defer` by default

```
<script type="module">
      import { ethers } from "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ethers/5.7.2/ethers.esm.js";
      const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
      const balance = await provider.getBalance(
        "0xE0552897c6495D7efb98F3823cd48bf19e703D0b"
      );
      console.log("========== balance =", balance);
</script>
```

From this [github post](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/2967)

> A lot of projects are using production levels of bandwidth from the
> ethers CDN to load their JavaScript, which I can no longer afford to
> operate at that scale.
>
> If you are linking to cdn.ethers.io or cdn-cors.ethers.io, you should
> switch to using the relevant link provided on [cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/ethers).
>
> Feedback is welcome, and I apologize for the inconvenience.
>
> Thanks!